# PHP lookup table

Tags: php

I have a chart in my hand that looks something like the following. It's likely these values will never change.

```
+----------------------+
|Rating | >=   | <=    |
+----------------------+
| 100   | 0.0  | 0.112 |
|  99   | 0.113| 0.156 |
|  98   | 0.157| 0.201 |
|  97   | 0.202| 0.309 |
| ...   | ...  | ...   |
+----------------------+
```

What is the best way to implement a function like `get_rating(0.300)` in PHP?

Of course I could make a long if/else chain or a switch statement. Not sure if that is the best solution, though.

Comment: Are you expecting `get_rating` to query database? What sort of database you are using?

Comment: It could be a database or an array. The values will likely never change so it seems a waste to use a database.

Comment: Can you include your thoughts into your question? Is so blur to me.

Comment: If you don't understand it then you should skip this question. I'm not just looking for any solution and I don't need "help", I'm looking for a theoretical discussion on the best solution. Thanks, though.

Comment: Well, is not that I don't understand your question. Is just the way you asking the question is so blur. Look at the two answers posted.

Comment: I think you should mention that. There is nothink to diccuss. Use DB or use array search. Unless that is CSV. Then you make it to the array and then use array_search.

Comment: So add these 100 rows to a database and do `select rating from table where 0.300 between col1 and col2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an array of the lower edges of range:

```
$ratings = array( 100 => 0, 99 => 0.113, 98 => 0.157, 97 => 0.202 ...);
```

and then find minimum value from array which is higher than your input value plus 1. Then you return the key of that value.

but... personally I think that if you use database for something already then `SQL BETWEEN` statement will be the best choice. 
With database you can too store only lower edges of range with rating equivalent. It will be easier to change values in the future and then you have ***something like***:

```
SELECT MAX(rating) FROM chart WHERE $val < lower
```

Then the database query will only need and use 2 columns:

```
+--------------+
|Rating | lower|
+--------------+
| 100   | 0.0  |
|  99   | 0.113|
|  98   | 0.157|
|  97   | 0.202|
| ...   | ...  |
+--------------+
```